# How to line up a text form with the background image?

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

Okay, so I'm trying to make a page that looks like the XP login screen, and I want a password form over the image's password box.
[Here's a picture to make it a little more clear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYoUV.png)

How do I line up the form with the image to make it look like you're typing into Windows XP **while also keeping it lined up when the page is resized?**

Here's my code, if it helps.

```
<html>
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>the meadow</title>
      <style>
    
    body {
      background-color: black;
      background-image: url('images/meadowlogin.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center top;
    }
    
    /* alt hides a copy of the backround so the alt text can be read by a screen reader*/ 
    .alt {
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
      border: 0;
    }
    
    .sticky {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 70%;
      width:20%;
    }
    
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
  
    <div class="alt"> <img src="images/meadowlogin.png" alt="A Windows XP login screen with the text edited to say 'Microsoft Meadows XP.' 
      There is a guest user and a user named 'The Meadow' which is currently selected.">
    </div>

    <img class="sticky" src="images/password.png" alt="A sticky note taped onto the screen reads 'Password 1234' with a smiley face.">
    
    <form>
    <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd">
    </form>
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @PeterJames meadowlogin.png is the XP login page (the entire screen) that I linked in the main post. password.png is the sticky note to the side. What I am trying to do is put a password input over the screenshot to make it look like you are typing into XP. I don't know how to line it up and also keep it lined up when the window is resized. The final layout looks exactly like the image I linked except when you click on the text box below the user you will be able to actually type.

Comment: I changed the meadowlogin.png image to be the background of a div instead of the background of the page, also.

Comment: @PeterJames I no longer need help, but thank you for commenting!